# how to use so file in ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want to use a .so file in the ros.  And I add the .h and .so file in the /usr/include/
What else should I do? Thanks very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189950/how-to-use-so-file-in-ros/) by [general_zclu](https://answers.ros.org/users/20003/general_zclu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Putting files by hand into /usr/include isn't a nice solution to your problem.

If this header file and library is contained in a debian package then the perfect solution is to simply depend on that package.

If this isn't the case but you have the source code of the library you can create an own package for it.

These two steps are recommended in the [ROS Wiki Using thrid party libs](http://wiki.ros.org/UsingThirdPartyLibraries).

If you haven't got access to the code you out the header and library inside your package and link the library with`target_link_libraries`

**Edit:**

I wouldn't put everything in `src`. I would put the headers in `include` and the shared objects in `lib`. In your CMakeLists.txt there's a boilerplate `target_link_libraries`. Add there the location of the shared object.

For example:

```
target_link_libraries(your_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libxyz.so)
```

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [general_zclu](https://answers.ros.org/users/20003/general_zclu/) on 2014-08-13**:
Thanks very much!  I haven't got access to the code. I have put the files .h and .so in ~/catin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src and I don't know how to write the CMakeLists, would you please tell me the details on how to write "target_link_library" and other place need to write. Thanks!

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-08-14**:
See my edit

**Comment by [general_zclu](https://answers.ros.org/users/20003/general_zclu/) on 2014-08-14**:
Thanks very much! And I wonder how to use the function in .so. When I just include ".h", and use the function in the .so, catkin_make say cannot find the function. If I need  #include "dlfcn.h" and use dlopen and dlsym to get the function? Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [khairulizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25088/khairulizwan/) on 2015-11-23**:
Hi..I a have a doubt here...

### Declare a C++ library

## add_library(iarm_exact_dynamics

## src/${PROJECT_NAME}/iarm_exact_dynamics.cpp

## )

whats is this for?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-11-23**:
@khairulizwan This compiles a library called iarm_exact_dynamics from the given source file.

**Comment by [khairulizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25088/khairulizwan/) on 2015-12-16**:
Still in doubt/unclear about this.
I am trying the create the iARM package.
iARM manufacturer provided the .h file, .lib file and also .so file.
Are this procedure correct:

1. copy the .h file --> include (mkdir -p include?)
2. copy the .so file --> lib (mkdir -p lib?)
3. edit the CMakelist.txt

**Comment by [khairulizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25088/khairulizwan/) on 2015-12-16**:
How about .lib file?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-12-17**:
@khairulizwan yes, I'd say that's the correct approach. I never worked with .lib files but it should work the same way.